# An error occurred while pushing in the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin / mobile'

Tags: git, github

I have an error in git like that in the title. How can I solve it?

This is the error:
**An error occurred while pushing in the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin / mobile'**

Comment: Can you paste the entire command how did you pushed?

Answer (score 0):

hmm it means that you you provide wrong reference to target the remote branch
try to see the available remote branch with:

```
git branch -a
```

checkout to the branch you desire, then do push from there

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the entire command what you gave, I suspect you gave the invalid reference while pushing your local repo to server.

What you need to do is

```
git push origin <your_branch_name>
```

I suspect you're adding something extra during the push that is why it complains as the invalid reference.

What error says? You are not using the valid ref i.e, `refspec`. This `refspec` points git to map references from remote to local repo.

---

**Usage:**

Dont use like this

```
git push origin <git@git.......>
```

example.

use `git push origin <https://github.com/your_repo.git>`